# Unable to add the 'React Script Editor Web Part' to a SharePoint Online Communication Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx-webparts

I have a question regarding a **SharePoint Online App installation** and using it on a **SharePoint Online SiteCollection**. The site template is a '**Communication**' site.

I used the below articles to install the app.

1. https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2020/11/add-custom-css-to-sharepoint-online-modern-page.html
2. https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/12/deploy-app-to-app-catalog-in-sharepoint-online.html
3. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/serve-your-web-part-in-a-sharepoint-page

Please refer the below points.

1. The App targeted to install 'Modern Script Editor Web Part'. This is also called as '**React Script Editor Web Part**'
2. The app was successfully installed on the Sp Online 'App Catalog' site. Please refer to the screenshot below.
   [image: AppStore SC]
3. Once uploaded to the App-Catalog site, I saw it in the SharePoint Online site under 'Site Contents'. Please refer to the below screenshot.
   [image: Site Content SC]
4. However when I tried to add it to a page(a site page), it didn't show up in the 'Web part picker'. Please refer to the below screenshot.
   [image: Site WebPart Picker Sc]
5. The 'Modern Script Editor Web Part' is activated as a site feature in the 'Site features' of the SharePoint Online site that intend to use it.
   [image: Site feature SC]

I can't understand what I'm missing. I have tried several times. But was not successful. Please can someone help me to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Did you enable custom scripts on your tenant?

Answer (score 1):

Please enable custom script in SharePoint Online using PowerShell at the site collection level.

```
#Config Parameters
$AdminSiteURL="https://crescent-admin.sharepoint.com"
$SiteURL="https://crescent.sharepoint.com"
   
#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential
   
#Connect to SharePoint Online Tenant Admin
Connect-SPOService -URL $AdminSiteURL -Credential $Cred
   
#sharepoint online enable custom scripts powershell - Disable DenyAddAndCustomizePages Flag
Set-SPOSite $SiteURL -DenyAddAndCustomizePages $False
```

If you want to enable it at tenant level, please go to SharePoint admin center>Settings>classic settings page>choose the related setting and allow it:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Julie_MSFT, I have tried PowerShell commands mentioned above. However unfortunately I got an error after executing `Connect-SPOService -URL $AdminSiteURL -Credential $Cred`. The error is **Connect-SPOService : The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system.
At line:1 char:1**.  I have given the admin account details to the pop-up input box after executing the previous command, **$Cred = Get-Credential**
I have also used the feature from **Classic Settings page' allowed **Custom Script**. However the app **is not enabled** in tenant level.

Comment: I also noticed that, in my root site the app is activated. I also tested it out and it works there perfectly.

Comment: If you find any reply helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer, it will help others who have the same issue.

Comment: Hi @Julie_MSFT,
Actually, my issue is not fully resolved. That's why I didn't mark a comment as an answer. Could you kindly assist me to solve the issue when I tried to execute the Powershell commands as mentioned in my previous reply? I think I cannot deploy the app at the tenant level. Can you explain what I have done wrong?

Regards,
Chiranthaka

Comment: Refer this article to solve the "sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system” Error in SharePoint Online:
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2020/07/fix-sign-in-name-password-does-not-match-one-in-microsoft-account-system-error.html